# Class of finite groups aren't axiomatizable - no equational class

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

*Let K be the class of all finite groups. Show that it is not a variety (closed under H, S, and P) and therefore not an equational class.*

It sounds pretty reasonable that K is closed under H and S. I guess you can create some direct product leading to an infinite group then, but why is it so? Shouldn't every direct product of finite groups again be finite? Of course, I have an uncountable amount of finite groups, but still I have to end at some point for my product.. and it should therefore again be finite.

Comment: No, a variety is closed under all products, not just finite ones.

Comment: Thank you. I thought from the definition of a product it has to be finite, e.g.: $$\mathcal{A} = \prod_{i \in I} A_i $$

So I can be infinite too? E.g. the natural numbers?

Comment: Right. There is no requirement there that $I$ is a finite set.